# How can I shutdown the system every day at a specific time

Tags: xubuntu, shutdown

Alright, so this is kind of stupid. I've already accomplished this but can't figure out how I did it now that I want to disable it. As it stands, the computer will shut down at 16:30 every day. It sends out a broadcast message in terminal when it gets close as well.

I must have somehow added the shutdown command to a startup entry somewhere, but I can't find it. There is nothing under ~/.config/autostart or under the startup applications list in settings.

Can anybody help me figure out another way that this is possible? (Because that's how i did it)

Comment: Perhaps you did it with cron ? Type crontab -e to see if it's in your cron tasks.

Comment: Look at `root`'s `crontab in `/etc/cron.d /etc/cron.daily /etc/cron.hourly /etc/cron.monthly /etc/crontab /etc/cron.weekly`, and look at everybody else's crontabs in `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/`, and just to be complete `/var/spool/cron/atjobs/`. Find the one containing the broadcast message.

Comment: It appears i did not use crontab...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yay! Figured out how I did it!

The file `/etc/rc.local` evidently runs on bootup. Adding the line `sudo shutdown -h 16:30` and then following that line with `exit 0` shut the system down each day at that time if it was on.